# change between string and bytes in python3

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, unicode, arrays

In python 2.7:

```
>>> x1= '\xba\xba'
>>> x2=b'\xba\xba'
>>> x1==x2
True
```

In python 3.4:

```
>>> x1='\xba\xba'
>>> x2=b'\xba\xba'
>>> x1==x2
False
>>> type(x1)
<class 'str'>
>>> type(x2)
<class 'bytes'>
```

1. how to change `x1` into `x2`?
2. how to change `x2` into `x1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3.x, use [`str.encode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) (str -> bytes) and [`bytes.decode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) (bytes -> str) with latin1 encoding (or iso-8859-1):

```
>>> x1 = '\xba\xba'
>>> x2 = b'\xba\xba'
>>> x1.encode('latin1') == x2
True
>>> x2.decode('latin1') == x1
True
```

Comment: `'\xba\xba'.encode('latin1')` -> `UnicodeDecodeError` on Python 2.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, in Python 2.x, `'\xba\xba' == b'\xba\xba'` (assuming no `from __future__ import unicode_literals`); no need to encode it. They are both byte strings.

Comment: The quesiton has code in both Python 2 and 3. You should specify the Python version you expect the code example to work if your code can't work on both.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, The question title mentioned `Python 3`. Anyway, I will specify the version. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Both `x1` and `x2` are bytestrings in Python 2. If you compare Unicode and bytes on Python 2; you also get `False` in this case:

```
>>> u'\xba\xba' == b'\xba\xba'
__main__:1: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
False
```

`x1` is a Unicode string in Python 3.

You could add `from __future__ import unicode_literals` to make the code work the same on both Python 2 and 3:

```
>>> from __future__ import unicode_literals
>>> x1 = '\xab\xab'
>>> type(x1)
<type 'unicode'>
```

Don't mix bytestrings and Unicode strings.

To convert Unicode string to bytes:

```
bytestring = unicode_string.encode(character_encoding)
```

To convert bytes to Unicode string:

```
unicode_string = bytestring.decode(character_encoding)
```